# How to fix Default document not configured error in C# Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net

When I run my application, I am getting "A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server." error.

I enabled directory browsing it didn't help either.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What type of project?

Comment: Are you suppose to be starting multiple projects rather than just the core? I take it one of those other projects is your front end. If that is the case You may need to go into your debug options and enable multi project and then select the projects you want to load, normally your back end and front end.

Comment: @maccettura .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: @Caz1224 this is all back-end. I have another C# project that is the front end. This is entirely serving as a service. All I am expecting this to do is to run without giving errors. When I run the front-end, that will connect to this to make certain queries to the server...

Comment: @Peace If this isn't supposed to have a UI, then why do you think you need to configure a default document? Just type the proper URL that maps to the URL's you expose for your service.

Comment: @mason good point. So whatever calling this from front end (which I would need to figure out, right?) I Need to change that to Url set for this project. That's what I am understanding...

Comment: @mason also, everytime I run this back-end, I am getting an error looking browser page. Should I ignore that then?

Comment: If your browser is requesting a page that does not exist, then sure, you should expect a 404. If you're tired of seeing that, then add a some sort of landing page to your service. I often do that, even if the only thing it says is "The service is running". You could even spice it up a bit by adapting some simple HTML/CSS that you can drop on this page, like [this](https://gist.github.com/pitch-gist/2999707).

Comment: @mason great tip, thank you!

Comment: To anyone experiencing same issue here, when I figure out why I keep getting this, I will update here.